# Why is sed outputting no text?

Tags: command-line, text

I have a text file that I need to remove double quotes from. I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58473/how-to-remove-all-instances-of-a-particular-symbol-from-a-text-file#58474) question that suggested using the following:

```
sed 's/"//g' < infile > outfile
```

I understand what it's doing as I'm familiar with Vim. But the output file has zero bytes in it after the command is run.

I did try the other suggestion from that question:

```
tr -d \" < infile > outfile
```

This results in an error:

```
tr: Illegal byte sequence
```

Note that when I open the file in MacVim and use

```
:%s /"//g
```

it works perfectly.

Is there some difference in macOS's `sed`? Any other suggestion on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the file is in UTF-16 format, but most of the text-manipulation tools in macOS don't know how to work with that and will garble files if they try. UTF-16 uses two bytes per character; for plain-ASCII characters like `"`, it's the single-byte ASCII code followed by a null byte. Something like `tr -d \"` will delete the first byte, leaving a stray null byte and throwing the entire rest of the file off by one byte.

I think you can get perl to work in UTF-16 (see [here](https://www.perl.com/pub/2012/05/perlunicook-specify-a-files-encoding.html/)), but I'm not sure of the ins and outs. This *might* work (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447653/stream-process-utf-16-file-with-bom-and-unix-line-endings-in-windows-perl)):

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { binmode $_, ":raw:encoding(UTF-16LE)" for *STDIN, *STDOUT }; s/"//g;' infile >outfile
```

You could also convert it to UTF-8 and back with

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 infile | tr -d \" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE >outfile
```

If the output doesn't need to be in UTF-16, you can leave the last `iconv` out.

Comment: I used the `iconv` version of this, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know exactly why this problem is happening, although I did find a bit more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953667/illegal-byte-sequence-error-while-using-shell-commands-in-mac-bash-terminal) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704020/recursive-search-and-replace-in-text-files-on-mac-and-linux), neither of which worked. I think it's the encoding and that the `LC_CTYPE=C` might be on the right track, but it converted the text into something completely different because of some sort of encoding problem.

Regardless, I did solve it, for now, at least, with this:

```
vim -c '%s /"//g|wq' infile
```

Comment: Are you sure this is really a plain text file? Try `file infile` and see what it says about the format. Also, are you trying to output to the same filename as you're reading from?

Comment: `file infile` outputs `Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines`, and yes, I did (eventually) want the file to be overwritten, but only once I was sure it was working.